# Android browser touch event location

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

On Safari, you can get the location of where the user touched the screen from event.pageX and event.pageY. However, on my Android browser, event.pageX and event.pageY are always 0. Is there any way to get the location of a touch event in the browser on Android?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish? Are you also interested in native options? E.g. like with any view, you can hook up a OnTouchListener to WebView and request the touch coordinates. Obviously, this will not work when zoomed in though. If you're after specific page elements, [`getHitTestResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getHitTestResult%28%29) might also be worth looking at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from memory, since I don't own an Android device anymore, but I think it's right. At the very least, it should get you started in the right direction. Good luck.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
elem.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    var pageX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX,
        pageY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been spending way too long trying to figure this out.